# How do i set placeholder char(%)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, placeholder

In Objective-c ...
I want represent placeholder char(%)
but my code don't....

```
NSString *base = @"<style type=\"test/css\">div{width:100\%}</style><body>%@</body>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:base, @"hello world"];
NSLog(@"%@",html);
```

- expect : div{width:100%}
- real : div{width:100}

what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *base = @"<style type=\"test/css\">div{width:100%%}</style><body>%@</body>";
```

The full list of format specifiers is [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).